# Consistent random set of posts with stickies

Tags: wordpress, random, pagination, sticky

Using WordPress, on my main page I'd like to be able to make a query of random posts that are consistent throughout a pagination, while stickies are still shown first. I've gotten as far as to create a consistent flow but I'm missing out on the stickies which show up randomly like the rest of the posts.

```
function custom_query($query) {
    global $custom_query;
    if ( $custom_query && strpos($query, 'ORDER BY RAND()') !== false ) {
        $query = str_replace( 'ORDER BY RAND()', $custom_query, $query );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'query', 'custom_query' );
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$seed = $_SESSION['seed'];

if ( empty($seed) ) {
    $seed = rand();
    $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
}

global $custom_query;
$custom_query = " ORDER BY rand($seed) ";

$args = array(
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

query_posts($args);
$custom_query = '';
```

Edit: Based on your suggestions I managed to solve it using the code below:

```
$sticky_post_ids = get_option('sticky_posts');
function mam_posts_query($query) {
   global $mam_posts_query;
   if ($mam_posts_query && strpos( $query, 'ORDER BY RAND()') !== false ) {
      $query = str_replace( 'ORDER BY RAND()', $mam_posts_query, $query );
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'query','mam_posts_query' );
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$seed = date('Ymdh'); // Sets an hourly random cache
global $mam_posts_query;
$mam_posts_query = " ORDER BY rand($seed) ";

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
);
$projects = query_posts($args);
$mam_posts_query = '';

if ( $paged === 1 ) {
    $stickies = get_posts( array('include' => $sticky_post_ids) );
    $projects = array_merge( $stickies, $projects );
}
```

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I would avoid ORDER BY RAND() in the query, it's a rather slow query argument. You can randomize with php instead... Do you want ALL your stickies to be on top of every page? Or just have the sticky post that happens to be in the randomized custom_query for that particular page?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, all stickies first in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the description in the [codex wp_query pag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters)e  is a bit confusing , but I believe that all you need to do is set

`'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0`.

That in my experiments worked, but of course while dealing with queries , I do not know where or when in another location might your query have changes ..

At any rate , if that does not work for you , you can also get the stickies with

`$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );`

and then set the query like this :

`'post__in'       => get_option('sticky_posts')`

or even so : (note the `not_in`)

```
 $query->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
```

Do note that by default the stickies are shown only on the home page .

you might also use a double loop approach :

```
$stickyQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat'                    => $your_category,// example   
        'ignore_sticky_posts'    => 0,
        'post__in'               => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'posts_per_page'         => -1             //Get ALL and ONLY the stickies, or how many you want
    );
while( $stickyQuery->have_posts() ) : $stickyQuery->the_post();

   //... ( Sticky Posts should show )

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

//... ( Continue main query or start a new one excluding the last.... )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind showing the same random posts to all visitors, you could use a transient and get_posts():

```
$my_random_posts = get_transient('my_random_posts');
if (!$my_random_posts) {
  $sticky_post_ids = get_option('sticky_posts');
  $my_random_posts = get_posts(array(
                                 'exclude' => $sticky_post_ids,
                                 'orderby' => 'rand',
                               ));

  if ($sticky_post_ids) {
    $sticky_posts = get_posts(array(
                                 'include' => $sticky_post_ids,
                               ));
    $my_random_posts = array_merge($sticky_posts, $my_random_posts);
  }

  set_transient('my_random_posts', $my_random_posts , 900); # 15 minutes
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, never heard of transients before. How would I apply this to a query? Tried running it as is but it just outputs random posts (also reappearing).

Comment: After actually testing it, I edited the code slightly to fix an issue when $sticky_post_ids is empty. Else it works fine on my end. transients are a bit like options, except that they reside in the persistent object cache (rather than the db) if one is available. As a result of this, you can set an expiration time (15 minutes in my example)

Comment: Btw, I'm unsure of what you mean by how you should apply this to a query. `$my_random_posts` returns the posts very much like `$WP_Query` does, for e.g. use in widgets and such.

Comment: @Denis, I believe one of us misunderstood the question (it might as well be me :- ) ) but i think the whole point was that he wanted the stickies to be taken out of the random query and put above , and then not show duplicate ..

Comment: I'm getting the impression we both misunderstood and that what he really wants is to serve all posts in the main loop in a (consistent) random order. Whereas we both assumed he wanted to pull a few random posts to serve in a sidebar.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how I would run the $my_random_posts in this case in order to get the correct output, I didn't get the correct results simply using a foreach / setup_postdata. Printing the query seems to give the right results though.